# Mootools Script Working In Joomla 1.5, Not in 2.5?

Tags: joomla, mootools, joomla1.5, joomla1.7, joomla2.5

I have a script that I need to use in Joomla 2.5, however it seems it won't work with the new version? What are my options?

Here is the full code for the script of the file.

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"".JURI::base()."/modules/mod_imageshowcase/mootools-release-1.11.js\"></script>\n";
}
echo 
    "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n".
    "var praiseShowStartImage_".$moduleInstanceId." = '".$startImage."';\n".
    "var praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." = '".$imageOrder."';\n".
    "var praiseShowPingPong_".$moduleInstanceId." = ".$pingPong.";\n".
    "var praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." = ".$index.";\n".
    "var praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId." = new Array();\n".
    "var praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.";\n".
    "var praiseShowPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." = ".$playCount.";\n".
    "var praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." = 0;\n".
    "if(praiseShowStartImage_".$moduleInstanceId." == 'random')\n".
    "{\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.");\n".
    "}\n".
    "else if(praiseShowStartImage_".$moduleInstanceId." == 'last_seen')\n".
    "{\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = Cookie.get('praiseShowLastIndex_".$moduleInstanceId."');\n".
    "   if(!praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.") { praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = 0; }\n".
    "}\n".
    "else if(praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." == 'backward')\n".
    "{\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." - 1;\n".
    "}\n".
    "else\n".
    "{\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = 0;\n".
    "}\n".
    "window.addEvent('domready',function() {\n".
    $domreadyScript.
    "});\n".
    "window.addEvent('load',function() {\n".
    "   var coords = $('".$containerTagId."').getCoordinates();\n".
    "   var elImage;\n".
    "   var elImageCoords;\n".
    "   $$('.mod_imageshowcase_div_".$moduleInstanceId."').each(function(el, i)\n".
    "   {\n".
    "       elImage = el.getElement('.mod_imageshowcase_image');\n";

if($imageScaleMode == "fit_both" || $imageScaleMode == "fit_height")
{
    echo "          elImage.setStyle('height', coords.height + 'px');\n";
}
if($imageScaleMode == "fit_both" || $imageScaleMode == "fit_width")
{
    echo "          elImage.setStyle('width', coords.width + 'px');\n";
}

if($imageScaleMode != "fit_both")
{
    switch($imageVerticalAlign)
    {
        case "top":
            $jsVerticalAlignText = "0";
            break;
        case "center":
            $jsVerticalAlignText = "(coords.height/2 - elImageCoords.height/2)";
            break;
        case "bottom":
        default:
            $jsVerticalAlignText = "(coords.height - elImageCoords.height)";
            break;
    }
    switch($imageHorizontalAlign)
    {
        case "left":
            $jsHorizontalAlignText = "0";
            break;
        case "center":
            $jsHorizontalAlignText = "(coords.width/2 - elImageCoords.width/2)";
            break;
        case "right":
        default:
            $jsHorizontalAlignText = "(coords.width - elImageCoords.width)";
            break;
    }
    echo
        "       elImageCoords = elImage.getCoordinates();\n".
        "       elImage.setStyle('left', ".$jsHorizontalAlignText." + 'px');\n".
        "       elImage.setStyle('top', ".$jsVerticalAlignText." + 'px');\n";
}
echo 
    "       if(i == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.") { el.setStyle('opacity', 1); }\n".
    "       else { el.setStyle('opacity', 0); }\n".
    "       praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId."[i] = new Fx.Style(el, 'opacity', {\n".
    "           wait: false,\n".
    "           duration: " . $transition_time . ",\n".
    "           transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut\n".
    "       });\n".
    "   });\n".
    "   switchImage_".$moduleInstanceId.".periodical(" . ($delay_time + $transition_time) . ");\n".
    "});\n".
    "var switchImage_".$moduleInstanceId." = function()\n".
    "{\n".
    "   var nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.";\n".
    "   switch(praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId.")\n".
    "   {\n".
    "       case 'random':\n".
    "           while(nextImageIndex == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." && praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." > 0)\n".
    "           {\n".
    "               nextImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.");\n".
    "           }\n".
    "           break;\n".
    "       case 'backward':\n".
    "           nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." - 1;\n".
    "           if(nextImageIndex < 0) {\n".
    "               if(praiseShowPingPong_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "                   praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." = 'forward';\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = 1;\n".
    "                   praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."++;\n".
    "               } else {\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." - 1;\n".
    "               }\n".
    "           }\n".
    "           break;\n".
    "       default:\n".
    "           nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." + 1;\n".
    "           if(nextImageIndex >= praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "               if(praiseShowPingPong_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "                   praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." = 'backward';\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." - 2;\n".
    "                   praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."++;\n".
    "               } else {\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = 0;\n".
    "               }\n".
    "           }\n".
    "           break;\n".
    "   }\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."++;\n".
    "   if(praiseShowPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." == 0 || praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." < praiseShowPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."*praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "       praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId."[praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId."].start(1, 0);\n".
    "       praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId."[nextImageIndex].start(0, 1);\n".
    "       praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = nextImageIndex;\n".
    "       Cookie.set('praiseShowLastIndex_".$moduleInstanceId."', praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.");\n".
    "   }\n".
    "}\n".
    "</script>\n";
```

View Source:

```
<body id="page_bg" class="color_blue bg_blue width_fmax">
<a name="up" id="up"></a>
<div class="center" align="center">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper_r">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="header_l">
                    <div id="header_r">
                        <div id="logo"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tabarea">
                <div id="tabarea_l">
                    <div id="tabarea_r">
                        <div id="tabmenu">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pill">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="pill_l">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="pill_m">
                                <div id="pillmenu">

                                </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="pill_r">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="search">

            </div>

            <div id="pathway">
                <link href="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/mod_imageshowcase.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div style="" class="mod_imageshowcase_container" id="mod_imageshowcase_containerTagId_16">
<div style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)" id="mod_imageshowcase_divIdPrefix_160" class="mod_imageshowcase_div mod_imageshowcase_div_16">
<img id="mod_imageshowcase_imageIdPrefix_160" class="mod_imageshowcase_image" src="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/testimages/CMS-Tactics-Inc-logo.gif" title="" />
<br />
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)" id="mod_imageshowcase_divIdPrefix_161" class="mod_imageshowcase_div mod_imageshowcase_div_16">
<img id="mod_imageshowcase_imageIdPrefix_161" class="mod_imageshowcase_image" src="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/testimages/beeheard-logo.png" title="" />
<br />
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)" id="mod_imageshowcase_divIdPrefix_162" class="mod_imageshowcase_div mod_imageshowcase_div_16">
<img id="mod_imageshowcase_imageIdPrefix_162" class="mod_imageshowcase_image" src="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/testimages/beeheardlite-logo.png" title="" />
<br />
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)" id="mod_imageshowcase_divIdPrefix_163" class="mod_imageshowcase_div mod_imageshowcase_div_16">
<img id="mod_imageshowcase_imageIdPrefix_163" class="mod_imageshowcase_image" src="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/testimages/cookiescrumbslogo3.png" title="" />
<br />
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)" id="mod_imageshowcase_divIdPrefix_164" class="mod_imageshowcase_div mod_imageshowcase_div_16">
<img id="mod_imageshowcase_imageIdPrefix_164" class="mod_imageshowcase_image" src="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/testimages/full_accesslevel-mid.jpg" title="" />
<br />
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)" id="mod_imageshowcase_divIdPrefix_165" class="mod_imageshowcase_div mod_imageshowcase_div_16">
<img id="mod_imageshowcase_imageIdPrefix_165" class="mod_imageshowcase_image" src="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/testimages/moo_menu_logo.jpg" title="" />
<br />
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)" id="mod_imageshowcase_divIdPrefix_166" class="mod_imageshowcase_div mod_imageshowcase_div_16">
<img id="mod_imageshowcase_imageIdPrefix_166" class="mod_imageshowcase_image" src="http://localhost/test//modules/mod_imageshowcase/testimages/playlistgen_dropdown.jpg" title="" />
<br />
</div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var praiseShowStartImage_16 = 'first';
var praiseShowImageOrder_16 = 'forward';
var praiseShowPingPong_16 = 0;
var praiseShowImageCount_16 = 7;
var praiseShowFxs_16 = new Array();
var praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16;
var praiseShowPlayCount_16 = 0;
var praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16 = 0;
if(praiseShowStartImage_16 == 'random')
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_16);
}
else if(praiseShowStartImage_16 == 'last_seen')
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = Cookie.get('praiseShowLastIndex_16');
    if(!praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16) { praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = 0; }
}
else if(praiseShowImageOrder_16 == 'backward')
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = praiseShowImageCount_16 - 1;
}
else
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = 0;
}
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
});
window.addEvent('load',function() {
    var coords = $('mod_imageshowcase_containerTagId_16').getCoordinates();
    var elImage;
    var elImageCoords;
    $$('.mod_imageshowcase_div_16').each(function(el, i)
    {
        elImage = el.getElement('.mod_imageshowcase_image');
        elImageCoords = elImage.getCoordinates();
        elImage.setStyle('left', (coords.width/2 - elImageCoords.width/2) + 'px');
        elImage.setStyle('top', (coords.height/2 - elImageCoords.height/2) + 'px');
        if(i == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16) { el.setStyle('opacity', 1); }
        else { el.setStyle('opacity', 0); }
        praiseShowFxs_16[i] = new Fx.Style(el, 'opacity', {
            wait: false,
            duration: 1500,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut
        });
    });
    switchImage_16.periodical(6500);
});
var switchImage_16 = function()
{
    var nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16;
    switch(praiseShowImageOrder_16)
    {
        case 'random':
            while(nextImageIndex == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 && praiseShowImageCount_16 > 0)
            {
                nextImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_16);
            }
            break;
        case 'backward':
            nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 - 1;
            if(nextImageIndex < 0) {
                if(praiseShowPingPong_16) {
                    praiseShowImageOrder_16 = 'forward';
                    nextImageIndex = 1;
                    praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16++;
                } else {
                    nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_16 - 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 + 1;
            if(nextImageIndex >= praiseShowImageCount_16) {
                if(praiseShowPingPong_16) {
                    praiseShowImageOrder_16 = 'backward';
                    nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_16 - 2;
                    praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16++;
                } else {
                    nextImageIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16++;
    if(praiseShowPlayCount_16 == 0 || praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16 < praiseShowPlayCount_16*praiseShowImageCount_16) {
        praiseShowFxs_16[praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16].start(1, 0);
        praiseShowFxs_16[nextImageIndex].start(0, 1);
        praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = nextImageIndex;
        Cookie.set('praiseShowLastIndex_16', praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16);
    }
}
</script>


            </div>

            <div class="clr"></div>

            <div id="whitebox">
                <div id="whitebox_t">
                    <div id="whitebox_tl">
                        <div id="whitebox_tr"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="whitebox_m">
                    <div id="area">


                        <div id="leftcolumn">
                                                            <div class="module_menu">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                                                    <h3>Main Menu</h3>
                                            <ul class="menu"><li id="current" class="active item1"><a href="http://localhost/test/"><span>Home</span></a></li></ul>                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

                                                </div>

                                                <div id="maincolumn">

                            <table class="nopad">
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="componentheading">
    Test</div>
<table class="blog" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
                </td>
</tr>


</table>


                                    </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="whitebox_b">
                    <div id="whitebox_bl">
                        <div id="whitebox_br"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="footerspacer"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footer_l">
                <div id="footer_r">
                    <p id="syndicate">

                    </p>
                    <p id="power_by">
                        Powered by <a href="http://www.joomla.org">Joomla!</a>.
                        valid <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">XHTML</a> and <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a>.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Rendered script only:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var praiseShowStartImage_16 = 'first';
var praiseShowImageOrder_16 = 'forward';
var praiseShowPingPong_16 = 0;
var praiseShowImageCount_16 = 7;
var praiseShowFxs_16 = new Array();
var praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16;
var praiseShowPlayCount_16 = 0;
var praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16 = 0;
if(praiseShowStartImage_16 == 'random')
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_16);
}
else if(praiseShowStartImage_16 == 'last_seen')
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = Cookie.get('praiseShowLastIndex_16');
    if(!praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16) { praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = 0; }
}
else if(praiseShowImageOrder_16 == 'backward')
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = praiseShowImageCount_16 - 1;
}
else
{
    praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = 0;
}
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
});
window.addEvent('load',function() {
    var coords = $('mod_imageshowcase_containerTagId_16').getCoordinates();
    var elImage;
    var elImageCoords;
    $$('.mod_imageshowcase_div_16').each(function(el, i)
    {
        elImage = el.getElement('.mod_imageshowcase_image');
        elImageCoords = elImage.getCoordinates();
        elImage.setStyle('left', (coords.width/2 - elImageCoords.width/2) + 'px');
        elImage.setStyle('top', (coords.height/2 - elImageCoords.height/2) + 'px');
        if(i == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16) { el.setStyle('opacity', 1); }
        else { el.setStyle('opacity', 0); }
        praiseShowFxs_16[i] = new Fx.Style(el, 'opacity', {
            wait: false,
            duration: 1500,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut
        });
    });
    switchImage_16.periodical(6500);
});
var switchImage_16 = function()
{
    var nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16;
    switch(praiseShowImageOrder_16)
    {
        case 'random':
            while(nextImageIndex == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 && praiseShowImageCount_16 > 0)
            {
                nextImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_16);
            }
            break;
        case 'backward':
            nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 - 1;
            if(nextImageIndex < 0) {
                if(praiseShowPingPong_16) {
                    praiseShowImageOrder_16 = 'forward';
                    nextImageIndex = 1;
                    praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16++;
                } else {
                    nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_16 - 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 + 1;
            if(nextImageIndex >= praiseShowImageCount_16) {
                if(praiseShowPingPong_16) {
                    praiseShowImageOrder_16 = 'backward';
                    nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_16 - 2;
                    praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16++;
                } else {
                    nextImageIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16++;
    if(praiseShowPlayCount_16 == 0 || praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_16 < praiseShowPlayCount_16*praiseShowImageCount_16) {
        praiseShowFxs_16[praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16].start(1, 0);
        praiseShowFxs_16[nextImageIndex].start(0, 1);
        praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16 = nextImageIndex;
        Cookie.set('praiseShowLastIndex_16', praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16);
    }
}
</script>
```

I believe it's currently on mootools v1.11. 
Thanks.

Comment: eeek looks like it got cut out, can you copy and paste from a view source in the browser? or provide a link?

Comment: It's on a localhost. I have edited the post and it should now contain the full script. If you like, I can copy a view source from a browser still?

Comment: yeah that would be great

Comment: Okay, the view source has now been added too.

Comment: sorry bro i need the javascript rendered source as well I could go through and clean out the PHP but that sounds like work ;)

Comment: Ahh okay, how do I provide that? Thanks for your patience! ;)

Comment: it is there i am just blind sry leaving the day job, will look further after my commute home

Comment: Okay I've added a third section that includes only the rendered script for you too. Thanks.

Comment: there are many issues with your code. in particular, Fx.Styles has been deprecated in favour of Fx.Tween and Fx.Morph, Cookie.get -> Cookie.read etc etc. Read the conversion guides and use fakedarren's 1.12 compatibility bridge to 1.2 to help you get upgraded, then once you do, drop it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok First thing that is glaring to me is this:

```
new Fx.Style(el, 'opacity', {
    wait: false,
    duration: 1500,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut
});
```

Change to:

```
new Fx.Tween(el, {
    link: 'cancel',
    duration: 1500,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut,
    property: 'opacity'
}).start(el.getStyle('opacity').toInt()?0:1);
```

Post back results and any errors in firebug (or equivalent);

UPDATE:
Actually better than this line

```
el.getStyle('opacity').toInt()?0:1
```

would be to also change:

```
if(i == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16) { el.setStyle('opacity', 1); }
        else { el.setStyle('opacity', 0); }
```

to

```
if(i == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_16) {
    var targetOpacity = 1;
    el.setStyle('opacity', targetOpacity);
} else {
    var targetOpacity = 0;
    el.setStyle('opacity', targetOpacity);
}
```

on on the start function pass:

```
new Fx.Tween(el, {
    link: 'cancel',
    duration: 1500,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut,
    property: 'opacity'
}).start(targetOpacity);
```

Updated PHP (no easy way top test may be minor errors)

```
    echo 
        "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n".
        "var praiseShowStartImage_".$moduleInstanceId." = '".$startImage."';\n".
        "var praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." = '".$imageOrder."';\n".
        "var praiseShowPingPong_".$moduleInstanceId." = ".$pingPong.";\n".
        "var praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." = ".$index.";\n".
        "var praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId." = new Array();\n".
        "var praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.";\n".
        "var praiseShowPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." = ".$playCount.";\n".
        "var praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." = 0;\n".
        "if(praiseShowStartImage_".$moduleInstanceId." == 'random')\n".
        "{\n".
        "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.");\n".
        "}\n".
        "else if(praiseShowStartImage_".$moduleInstanceId." == 'last_seen')\n".
        "{\n".
        "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = Cookie.get('praiseShowLastIndex_".$moduleInstanceId."');\n".
        "   if(!praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.") { praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = 0; }\n".
        "}\n".
    "else if(praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." == 'backward')\n".
    "{\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." - 1;\n".
    "}\n".
    "else\n".
    "{\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = 0;\n".
    "}\n".
    "window.addEvent('domready',function() {\n".
    $domreadyScript.
    "});\n".
    "window.addEvent('load',function() {\n".
    "   var coords = $('".$containerTagId."').getCoordinates();\n".
    "   var elImage;\n".
    "   var elImageCoords;\n".
    "   $$('.mod_imageshowcase_div_".$moduleInstanceId."').each(function(el, i)\n".
    "   {\n".
    "       elImage = el.getElement('.mod_imageshowcase_image');\n";

    if($imageScaleMode == "fit_both" || $imageScaleMode == "fit_height")
    {
    echo "          elImage.setStyle('height', coords.height + 'px');\n";
    }
    if($imageScaleMode == "fit_both" || $imageScaleMode == "fit_width")
    {
    echo "          elImage.setStyle('width', coords.width + 'px');\n";
    }

    if($imageScaleMode != "fit_both")
    {
    switch($imageVerticalAlign)
    {
    case "top":
    $jsVerticalAlignText = "0";
    break;
    case "center":
    $jsVerticalAlignText = "(coords.height/2 - elImageCoords.height/2)";
    break;
    case "bottom":
    default:
    $jsVerticalAlignText = "(coords.height - elImageCoords.height)";
    break;
    }
    switch($imageHorizontalAlign)
    {
    case "left":
    $jsHorizontalAlignText = "0";
    break;
    case "center":
    $jsHorizontalAlignText = "(coords.width/2 - elImageCoords.width/2)";
    break;
    case "right":
    default:
    $jsHorizontalAlignText = "(coords.width - elImageCoords.width)";
    break;
    }
    echo
    "       elImageCoords = elImage.getCoordinates();\n".
    "       elImage.setStyle('left', ".$jsHorizontalAlignText." + 'px');\n".
    "       elImage.setStyle('top', ".$jsVerticalAlignText." + 'px');\n";
    }
    echo 
    "       if(i == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.") { var targetOpacity = 1; el.setStyle('opacity', targetOpacity); }\n".
    "       else { var targetOpacity = 0; el.setStyle('opacity', targetOpacit); }\n".
    "       praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId."[i] = Fx.Tween(el, {\n".
    "           link: 'cancel',\n".
    "           duration: " . $transition_time . ",\n".
    "           transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut,\n".
    "           property: 'opacity'\n".
    "       }).start(targetOpacity);\n".
    "   });\n".
    "   switchImage_".$moduleInstanceId.".periodical(" . ($delay_time + $transition_time) . ");\n".
    "});\n".
    "var switchImage_".$moduleInstanceId." = function()\n".
    "{\n".
    "   var nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.";\n".
    "   switch(praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId.")\n".
    "   {\n".
    "       case 'random':\n".
    "           while(nextImageIndex == praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." && praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." > 0)\n".
    "           {\n".
    "               nextImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.");\n".
    "           }\n".
    "           break;\n".
    "       case 'backward':\n".
    "           nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." - 1;\n".
    "           if(nextImageIndex < 0) {\n".
    "               if(praiseShowPingPong_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "                   praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." = 'forward';\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = 1;\n".
    "                   praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."++;\n".
    "               } else {\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." - 1;\n".
    "               }\n".
    "           }\n".
    "           break;\n".
    "       default:\n".
    "           nextImageIndex = praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." + 1;\n".
    "           if(nextImageIndex >= praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "               if(praiseShowPingPong_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "                   praiseShowImageOrder_".$moduleInstanceId." = 'backward';\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId." - 2;\n".
    "                   praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."++;\n".
    "               } else {\n".
    "                   nextImageIndex = 0;\n".
    "               }\n".
    "           }\n".
    "           break;\n".
    "   }\n".
    "   praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."++;\n".
    "   if(praiseShowPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." == 0 || praiseShowCurrentPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId." < praiseShowPlayCount_".$moduleInstanceId."*praiseShowImageCount_".$moduleInstanceId.") {\n".
    "       praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId."[praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId."].start(1, 0);\n".
    "       praiseShowFxs_".$moduleInstanceId."[nextImageIndex].start(0, 1);\n".
    "       praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId." = nextImageIndex;\n".
    "       Cookie.set('praiseShowLastIndex_".$moduleInstanceId."', praiseShowCurrentImageIndex_".$moduleInstanceId.");\n".
    "   }\n".
    "}\n".
    "</script>\n";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these changes, I really appreciate it! However, I've gone to make these changes and have come across a problem. The code I need to edit is what you see in the first block of code (of the original post). It's surrounded by php code, and so I can't just copy the new code over.

Comment: you are correct it will take a bit of time to match things up

Comment: from 1.12 to 1.2: https://github.com/fakedarren/mootools-upgrade-helper or just use the built ver from the blog i think.

from 1.2 to 1.3: https://github.com/fakedarren/MooTools-1.3-Upgrade-Helper

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com Been trying to get my head around all of this but not to much avail, this is amazing thank you very much! . It shows an error of: **bold**Fx.Tween(el, {link: "cancel", duration: 1540, transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeInOut, property: "opacity"}).start is not a function
http://localhost/test
Line 182**bold** When I remove the start part, it displays an image, but when a change of image is supposed to happen, it give the same error about the start function?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Joomla 2.5 is using mooTools 1.4

Joomla 1.5 is using 1.12

Your only option is to manually update your mootools 1.12 code to mootools 1.4 standards.

There are numerous resource online to assist you in this.

Do you have a link to your code that is not working?

This link will help you in moving from 1.1 to 1.2 (at this point you could download and use the moo compatibility layer [not recommended]):
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Conversion-from-1.11-to-1.2-

This link will take you from 1.2 to 1.3:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Upgrade-from-1.2-to-1.3

At this point you should be good MooTools 1.4 add core improvements most notably the selector engine upgrade and event delegation (previously only found in more)

read more at: http://mootools.net/blog/2011/09/10/mootools-1-4-0/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Looking at those links, I think I'm a little out of my depth here. So what would I actually need to do to "upgrade". Would I need to replace and old methods with the new methods brought forward?